# iText 7 watermark canvas not appearing correctly in some special 3d pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have been using iText7 latest .net package to create watermark annotation on pdf document. I see for most of the noraml pdf files watermark is stamped properly in the desired position however for some special 3d(dimensional) pdf files the watermark is strangely not appearning properly, what I believe that some part of the watermark is gettting cut by the other 3d layers. Here is the screenshot of distortion experienced. I am trying to understand and solve this problem but unable to get any clue. Can someone help? Here is the [**sample pdf**](https://easyupload.io/i87vo4) in case you want to take a look.

[image]

Here is the very short relevant code which I am using to embed watermark.

```
            float watermarkTrimmingRectangleWidth = 500;
            float watermarkTrimmingRectangleHeight = 500;
            float formWidth = 500;
            float formHeight = 500;
            float formXOffset = -40;
            float formYOffset = 0;
            float xTranslation = 50;
            float yTranslation = 25;
            double rotationInRads = Math.PI / 4.2;

 PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(filePath), new PdfWriter(destinationfile));
 var numberOfPages = pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages();
 PdfPage page = null;

            for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++)
            {
                
                page = pdfDoc.GetPage(i);
                Rectangle ps = page.GetPageSize();              

                float bottomLeftX = ps.GetWidth() / 2 - watermarkTrimmingRectangleWidth / 2;                    
                float bottomLeftY = ps.GetHeight() / 2 - watermarkTrimmingRectangleHeight / 2;                  

                Rectangle watermarkTrimmingRectangle = new Rectangle(bottomLeftX, bottomLeftY, ps.GetWidth(), watermarkTrimmingRectangleHeight);
               
                PdfWatermarkAnnotation watermark = new PdfWatermarkAnnotation(watermarkTrimmingRectangle);
              
                AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
                transform.Translate(xTranslation, yTranslation);
                
                transform.Rotate(rotationInRads);
                PdfFixedPrint fixedPrint = new PdfFixedPrint();
                watermark.SetFixedPrint(fixedPrint);                  
               
                Rectangle formRectangle = new Rectangle(formXOffset, formYOffset, formWidth, formHeight);

                //Observation: font XObject will be resized to fit inside the watermark rectangle
                PdfFormXObject form = new PdfFormXObject(formRectangle);
                PdfExtGState gs1 = new PdfExtGState().SetFillOpacity(0.8f).SetStrokeOpacity(1.5f);
                PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(form, pdfDoc);
                float[] transformValues = new float[6];
                transform.GetMatrix(transformValues);

                canvas.SaveState()
                    .BeginText().SetExtGState(gs1)
                    .SetTextMatrix(transformValues[0], transformValues[1], transformValues[2], transformValues[3], transformValues[4], transformValues[5])
                    .SetFontAndSize(font, fontSize)
                    .ShowText("Restricted Internal")
                    .EndText()
                    .RestoreState();

                canvas.Release();
                watermark.SetAppearance(PdfName.N, new PdfAnnotationAppearance(form.GetPdfObject()));
                watermark.SetFlags(PdfAnnotation.READ_ONLY);
                page.AddAnnotation(watermark);
                
            }
            page?.Flush();
            pdfDoc.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your watermark annotation is drawn on top of some form fields. 
Because the display order for page elements is page content, annotations, form fields, your annotation appearance is blocked by the form fields.

Comment: Thanks I see, is there a way to workaround this? Can I bring the annotation layer on top.

Comment: 1. You can create your custom PDF viewer and define the display order you want or 2. Use a read-only locked text box field with a custom appearance that matches your watermark